# R Replace Data with NA

Tags: r, replace

Hy there I have a table with some observations in different depths, where i d like to replace the Value of few observations with NA, if the Value of Observation 7 is negative, but otherwise it should keep its value. 
For example, if obs 7 in depth=2 is negative (e.g. -8), replace the values of observation 1,2,7 and 9 with NA. Otherwise do nothing

```
worksheet <- some_data%>%
do_some_stuff%
mutate_at(vars(obs7,obs1,obs2,obs9), if_else(obs7<=0,NA, ??)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, we need to only change the values in the column where 'ob7' is less than or equal to 0.  In that case, the 'yes' part would be `NA` and the 'no' would be the data column itself.  In tidyverse, it would be represented as `.` as there is a `~`

```
library(tidyverse)
some_data %>%
      mutate_at(vars(obs7, obs1, obs2, obs9), list(~ ifelse(ob7 <= 0, NA, .)))
```

NOTE: Here, we are using `ifelse` instead of `if_else` as `if_else` is particular about type checking and from the question it is not clear about the type of columns of interest.  If the columns are integer, then replace `NA` with `NA_integer_` and if it is double, `NA_real_` within `if_else`

Comment: Could you just us `na_if()` from `dplyr`?

Comment: @Wil  I thought of `na_if`, but it takes a particular value instead of a condition.  If the OP wanted to replace all 0s, then `na_if(., y = 0)`

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Wil Just to test `na_if(1:5, y = (1:5) < 4)#
[1] NA  2  3  4  5`

Comment: I see. I wasn't reading the documentation closely enough. I was envisioning something like your example where the second argument could also be an expression that evaluates to a logical vector the same length as the first argument, such as `na_if(1:5,~ . < 0)`. Because I suspect behind the scenes they are doing that same thing anyway, where `na_if(letters,"c")` is ultimately just `letters[letters=="c"] <- NA`, so I assumed any logical expression would do.